# Can I delete specific data from SQL Server replication subscriber database without breaking replication?

Tags: sql-server, replication

The situation is this: We have a SQL Server replication subscriber database which receives replicated data from one of our core OLTP systems which we use as a source to populate our data warehouse. (also our OLTP database is hosted by a third party vendor).

To increase performance on the subscriber, I'd like to delete data rows which are older than a data retention limit we have established. We cannot do this in the publisher database and have the deletes replicate down because this would be cost prohibitive (vendor) and it may aggravate other business units using the front end.

I'd like to know if I can go ahead and perform the data retention deletes on the subscriber database without either (a) breaking replication somehow or (b) having replication simply re-populate those deleted rows. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. Rows that you delete on the subscriber will go and stay gone. Replication won't break on this because, at worst, a `DELETE` or  `UPDATE` statement could be replicated that will then not delete/update anything (which is not an error).

One important caveat, though: if you have to reinitialize the subscription (which may be necessary for various reasons, for example if data corruption occurs on the subscriber or some *CENSORED* inserts data that shouldn't have been inserted and replication breaks), a new snapshot will be generated that includes the deleted rows, which will then reappear on the subscriber. You'll have to re-run your deletes and take care they don't generate huge load if there are lots of rows to delete (by batching them, most likely).

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the replication breaks if you delete the same records from the publisher database as well. Because when the commands try to delete rows from the subscriber it gives an error since the actual records are not found.

I have tried this on a transactional replication. And I think same would happen with the Update command as well.